# Clean # symbol from Json object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json string, turned into a Javascript object which on one of its levels returns something like this

```
"link": {
            "#tail": "\n\n\t\t",
            "#text": "http://static2.server.com/file.mp3"
          },
```

I need to get the value of "text" on Javascript but the "#" symbol is making it imposible to access it.

I have tried cleaning the string like this:

```
var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(response);
      var myEscapedJSONString = myJSONString.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]+/g, "").replace("#","t");
```

But it does not clean the "key" part, even after it has been turned into a string using stringify.

Comment: You can access the object value in javascript even with the # in the key. Just use the notation link['#tail'] or link['#text'] instead

Comment: @nanndoj I tried it but it does not work on some devices. I'm using this code inside an Ionic app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with the # being used as a key. Any valid string can be used as object key. But if you really want to remove using strings you can replace it using regular expression (Assuming the hash char only in the beginning of each key);

```
const cleanObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response).replace(/\"#/gm,'"'))
console.log(cleanObj.link.text);
```

I could not find any problem also accessing and cleaning up through javascript

```
var cleanObject = { link: {} };

Object.keys(response.link).map(function(key) { 
    cleanObject.link[key.substring(1)] = response.link[key];
})
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/p5cvvqzu/

Answer (score 0):

What about stripping out the `#`s before you use the object?

```
function stripHashes(obj) {
    var strippedObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        strippedObj[key.substr(1)] = link[key];
    });
    return strippedObj;
}
```

This will return a new object with the hashes stripped from the input object's keys.

Comment: Note: this isn't recursive, but as your example data is only one level deep I didn't worry about it. If you do have nested objects, you could adapt this.

Comment: it's actually various levels deep, I'll try to adapt it and I'll let you know.